# Frob($\tilde{L}|K$) $\to$ $G(L|K)$ is surjective? (Algebraic Number Theory)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading the Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, p.287, (4.4) Proposition.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the underlined statements.

Q.1) What is $d_K(\sigma)$? By the page 285 in the above image, $d_K$ means a surjective homomorphism $d_K = \frac{1}{f_K} d : G_{K} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ or an isomorphism $d_K : G(\tilde{K}|K) \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. And p.276, $G(\tilde{L}|K) = G_K /G_{\tilde{L}}$. ($\tilde{L}|K$ is really galois in the sense of p.276? ; that is, $G_{\tilde{L}}$ is normal subgroup of $G_{K}$?)

Then for $\sigma \in G(\tilde{L}|K) = G_K /G_{\tilde{L}}$, we can write $\sigma = \sigma^{'} + G_{\tilde{L}}$, where $\sigma^{'}\in G_K$. Then $d_K(\sigma)$ means $d_K({\sigma^{'}})$?

If so, then this map is well defined? Why?

Q.2) In (4.4) Proposition, why such $\varphi \in G(\tilde{L}|K)$ exists? My first attempt is, since
$d_K = \frac{1}{f_K} d : G_{K} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a surjective homomorphism, there exists an element $\varphi_K \in G_K$ such that $d_K(\varphi_K) =1$. Then let $\varphi := \varphi_K + G_{\tilde{L}} \in G(\tilde{L}|K) $. Then $\varphi$ maps to  1 by the map in the Question 1). But the well-definedness of the map in Q.1) is problem. Is it true?

Comment: Please, for future posts, avoid pasting images. It's a lot better if you write the question instead of using a picture and people will be more likely to help you that way.

Comment: O.K. I will refer~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Q1 is answered by the next line:

> Observe here that $d_K : G_k \to \widehat{\Bbb Z}$ factorizes through $G(\tilde{L} | K)$ because $G_{\tilde{L}} = I_L \subseteq I_K$

Recall that $I_L$ is the kernel of $d|_{G_L}: G_L \to \widehat{\Bbb Z}$, and $G_L \subseteq G_K$, so $I_L \subseteq I_K$.

Also recall from the definition of "maximal unramified extension" that $I_L = G_{\tilde{L}}$.

Since $d|_{G_K}: K \to \widehat{\Bbb Z}$ sends $I_L$ to $0$, it factorizes through $I_L = G_{\tilde{L}}$ to give a map $d: G_K / G_{\tilde{L}} \to \widehat{\Bbb Z}$, i.e. $d: G(\tilde{L}|K) \to \widehat{\Bbb Z}$.

Then surely $d_K = \frac1{f_K} d$ is still well-defined as a function $d: G(\tilde{L}|K) \to \widehat{\Bbb Z}$.

---

Let $n \in I_L$ and $g \in G_K$. Now $G_L$ is normal in $G_K$, so $gng^{-1} \in G_L$. Also, $d(gng^{-1}) = d(n) = 0$, so $gng^{-1} \in I_L$.

Therefore, $I_L$ is normal in $G_K$, i.e. $\tilde{L}|K$ is Galois.

---

Yes, $d_K(\sigma) = d_K(\sigma')$.

---

For Q2, yes, that is how you construct $\varphi$.

Comment: Yes. Helpful comment. Especially, part of  that "$I_L \subseteq I_K$"  and  "$\tilde{L}|K$ is galois." Thank you ! :)